# GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to read a lazy initialized entity `ProductUnits` which is a persistent set, and opened a new session for the same.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.update(stock.getProduct());
List<ProductUnits> units = new ArrayList<ProductUnits>(stock.getProduct().getUnits());
```

The problem is during the run time it throws the exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [hibernate.tables.plain.Product#1]
```

but while doing a **step by step debug it runs perfectly fine**. Is it that the session.update takes some time or am I missing something

the exception stack is

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [hibernate.tables.plain.Product#2]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1895)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:71)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:65)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:434)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:415)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:863)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:95)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
at hibernate.tables.plain.Product_$$_javassist_15.getUnits(Product_$$_javassist_15.java)
at bill.mainBill.InputProductsPanel.computeStockAvailablity(InputProductsPanel.java:278)
at bill.mainBill.InputProductsPanel.findStock(InputProductsPanel.java:242)
at bill.mainBill.ProductDetailPanel.setStats(ProductDetailPanel.java:315)
at bill.mainBill.ProductDetailPanel$3.focusLost(ProductDetailPanel.java:187)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processFocusEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)


    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'N'
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2727)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2815)
at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:51)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2124)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1404)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1332)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1230)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:603)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1881)
... 48 more
```

then mapping file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 3, 2012 1:21:15 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="hibernate.tables.plain.ProductUnits" table="PRODUCT_UNITS">
  <composite-id mapped="false" unsaved-value="undefined">
   <key-many-to-one class="hibernate.tables.plain.Product"
    column="Product_ID" name="product"/>
   <key-many-to-one class="hibernate.tables.plain.Unit" column="Unit_ID" name="unit"/>
  </composite-id>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="basePrice" type="java.lang.Double">
   <column name="BASE_PRICE"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the product mapping

```
 <class name="hibernate.tables.plain.Product" table="PRODUCT">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="recommendedHolding" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="RECOMMENDED_HOLDING" />
        </property>
        <set name="units" table="Product_Units" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="Product_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many  class="hibernate.tables.plain.ProductUnits" />
        </set>
        <property name="active" type="java.lang.Character">
            <column name="ACTIVE" />
        </property>
    </class>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems that Hibernate is having a problem mapping a character value `N` to a `java.lang.Boolean`.

If you need to map `java.lang.Boolean` maybe it's better to use either `java.lang.Boolean` or `org.hibernate.type.YesNoType` instead of 'java.lang.Character'. You can read more in the [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic).

Or you need to use `java.lang.Character`, follow the [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom) to register a custom type.

Answer (score 2):

There's your problem:

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'N'
```

Comment: Well the point is I am not even able to figure out why this is coming there is no _INT_ datamember in the table or the entity. That probably refers to a `Character` field isActive. dont know if MYSQL treats character as int.

Comment: is the 'isActive' field part of the PRODUCT_UNITS table?

Comment: No its part of the Product table.

Answer (score 2):

Well Change the property type from Character to String

```
<property name="active" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="ACTIVE" />
</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your issue is arrising from your mapping settings:

```
 <composite-id mapped="false" unsaved-value="undefined">
```

**Note:**

> unsaved-value (optional - defaults to a "sensible" value): an
>   identifier property value that indicates an instance is newly
>   instantiated (unsaved), distinguishing it from detached instances that
>   were saved or loaded in a previous session.

The setting is causing `PRODUCT_UNITS` not to persist.

The `unsaved-value` attribute is almost never needed in Hibernate3.

Comment: But it still does not answer why does it run fine during debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I found another reference stating that hibernate casts a character to an int (even though the documentation state character is a usable data type...). The other answers should solve this. Or I would recommend you just use a varchar(1) instead - same end result.

ie)

```
@Column(name = "column", nullable = false, length = 1)
public String getColumn() {
    return column;
}
```

or

```
    <property name="active" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="ACTIVE" length="1"/>
    </property>
```

Answer (score -1):

please ,check persistence.xml file add the proper classes
Note:-Data Source of persistence.xml file is not properly matched

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.